# Azure DevOps pipeline condition - Why include "and always"?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In [the documentation for conditions in Azure DevOps pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#run-if-the-build-is-scheduled-even-if-failing-even-if-canceled) the following example is given:

```
and(always(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
```

Why would you include the "and(always()" part? To my understanding it is semantically equivalent to just:

```
 eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right Kristoffer, the two conditions are behaviourally equivalent.

I would offer one reason to use the long version though:

```
and(always(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
```

When writing task conditions, it is easy to forget that `succeeded()` is the default, and if you don't include it then your task will run even if the job is failing or cancelled.

So I think it would be a good practice to write all conditions with `succeeded()` (or `always()` or `cancelled()` or whatever) included in the expression; then if you see a condition *without it*, like this:

```
eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
```

then you are reminded to question whether the condition was intended to include failing/cancelled jobs or not.

Changing it to the long version takes away the risk of that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This example is titled as "***Run if the build is scheduled, even if failing, even if canceled***".

So, this condition:

```
eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
```

is for "*Run if the build is scheduled*" part.

And this condition:

```
always()
```

is for "*even if failing, even if canceled*" part.

Those two are composed with `and(...)`. That's it.

Comment: But I am correct in this correlates to adding "&& true" to a traditional logical statement and it is redundant?

Comment: No, I don't think so. That `always` predicate adds specific conditions. Treat it as the following (imaginary) predicates: `and(runIfFailing(), runIfCancelled())`

Comment: >Treat it as the following (imaginary) predicates: `and(runIfFailing(), runIfCancelled())`

If that is true, then the `and` function do not work like a logical "and". Looks like you are referring to logical "or".